# S3 UploadPartCopy: Invalid resource in copy source ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'd like to use UploadPartCopy to copy a large object from one region to another region (different accounts, no access points)

AWS cli returns following error:

```
~ aws s3api upload-part-copy \
    --bucket my-objects \
    --key "my-bucket/temp1.png" \
    --copy-source "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:123451980301:my-objects/my-bucket/temp.png" \
    --part-number 1 \
    --upload-id ".OjnTTL4zciiCx5U56ED89sgfWNfowZZYCn9iSxhYIThSI8Pqa.Fp1tg6KaiR4fbejyzCIvrzcTbUiMnIT3DGfoVQmQaZuMVDeA8q_OWomKDNmRNKtcH.cm0LRUtHjuJ"


An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Invalid resource in copy source ARN
```

Prior to this command, I used `create-multipart-upload` to get the upload id.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Read Marcin's answer below, but also take note that `arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:123451980301:my-objects/my-bucket/temp.png` is not a valid s3 object arn.  Both account and region are omitted in S3 arn.  `arn:aws:s3:::my-objects/my-bucket/temp.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--copy-source` should be in the format of:

```
my-bucket/temp.png
```

as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/upload-part-copy.html):

> For objects not accessed through an access point, specify the name of the source bucket and key of the source object, separated by a slash (/). For example, to copy the object reports/january.pdf from the bucket awsexamplebucket , use awsexamplebucket/reports/january.pdf

ARN is used for access points, not regular s3 objects.

Comment: Is it possible to copy from one region to another?

Comment: @Deqing No sure. You can make new question for that new issue.

Comment: thanks, I raised another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780889/does-s3-uploadpartcopy-support-copying-object-from-one-region-to-another