# Does S3 UploadPartCopy support copying object from one region to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'd like to copy a large object that over 5GB from one region to another region (different account).

In [the UploadPartCopy document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html) it says:

> Amazon S3 supports copy operations using access points only when the source and destination buckets are in the same AWS Region.

So looks like I can't use access point to copy between regions.

A regular s3 object url is `bucket-name\file-name`, how do I specify source region and the source account number in the UploadPartCopy API? Or, does S3 UploadPartCopy support copying object from one region to another?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, s3 objects up to 5GB in size may be copied between buckets, even when those buckets are in different regions.  You cannot use the accelerator but the API itself supports your need.

See the CLI documentation for the copy-object operation, which covers how to form the request (SDK operations in your programming will operate very similarly).

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html

Comment: Just revised my question, the object is over 5GB so will be using multipart upload APIs to copy.

Comment: In that case you just need to use the upload-part-copy API using the original (large) object as the source and specifying the byte range to include in the part. That works between buckets/region as well.
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/upload-part-copy.html

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I don't know how to specify source region and account in the upload-part-copy API.

Comment: The source region is simply the region of the source bucket.  Since buckets are globally unique by name, the bucket defines the account and region -- source and destination.  Your IAM authorization (role, or credentials) must provide access to both buckets/accounts.